# HBase HRegionServer can't startup

Tags: hbase

I have hadoop 2.7.3 and hbase 1.2.3. I tried to run hbase in Pseudo-Distributed mode following the official document. I have only one machine. HDFS is working well.

However the problem is when I executed start-hbase.sh, the HRegionServer startup but exit automatically. I can see the HMaster and HQuorumPeer are still there.

From the log, I think the hbase created a file /hbase/WALs/ubuntuserver,16201,1478832152563/ubuntuserver%2C16201%2C1478832152563..meta.1478832162907.meta but have no permission to append content into the file. Current user is 'ubuntuserver' in group 'root'. and I have changed all the folders on hdfs to 'ubuntuserver' and 'root'. And did 'hdfs dfs -chmod -R 777 /'. And restart linux, hdfs and then hbase. It doesn't work. Every time HResionServer started it would create a new file then have no permission to append to it.

Here is the log of HRegionServer. How to fix this?

> 2016-11-11 11:13:44,774 INFO 
>   [RS_OPEN_META-ubuntuServer:16201-0-MetaLogRoller]
>   regionserver.HRegionServer: STOPPED: Failed log close in log roller
>   2016-11-11 11:13:44,774 INFO 
>   [regionserver/ubuntuServer/10.0.2.15:16201]
>   regionserver.SplitLogWorker: Sending interrupt to stop the worker
>   thread 2016-11-11 11:13:44,775 INFO 
>   [regionserver/ubuntuServer/10.0.2.15:16201]
>   regionserver.HRegionServer: Stopping infoServer 2016-11-11
>   11:13:44,776 INFO  [SplitLogWorker-ubuntuServer:16201]
>   regionserver.SplitLogWorker: SplitLogWorker interrupted. Exiting.
>   2016-11-11 11:13:44,776 INFO  [SplitLogWorker-ubuntuServer:16201]
>   regionserver.SplitLogWorker: SplitLogWorker
>   ubuntuserver,16201,1478834015515 exiting 2016-11-11 11:13:44,780 INFO 
>   [RS_OPEN_META-ubuntuServer:16201-0-MetaLogRoller]
>   regionserver.LogRoller: LogRoller exiting. 2016-11-11 11:13:44,805
>   INFO  [regionserver/ubuntuServer/10.0.2.15:16201] mortbay.log: Stopped
>   SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:16301 2016-11-11 11:13:44,810 INFO 
>   [regionserver/ubuntuServer/10.0.2.15:16201]
>   regionserver.HeapMemoryManager: Stoping HeapMemoryTuner chore.
>   2016-11-11 11:13:44,810 INFO 
>   [regionserver/ubuntuServer/10.0.2.15:16201]
>   flush.RegionServerFlushTableProcedureManager: Stopping region server
>   flush procedure manager abruptly. 2016-11-11 11:13:44,810 INFO 
>   [regionserver/ubuntuServer/10.0.2.15:16201]
>   snapshot.RegionServerSnapshotManager: Stopping
>   RegionServerSnapshotManager abruptly. 2016-11-11 11:13:44,810 INFO 
>   [regionserver/ubuntuServer/10.0.2.15:16201]
>   regionserver.HRegionServer: aborting server
>   ubuntuserver,16201,1478834015515 2016-11-11 11:13:44,811 INFO 
>   [regionserver/ubuntuServer/10.0.2.15:16201]
>   client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Closing zookeeper
>   sessionid=0x158516036c10005 2016-11-11 11:13:44,813 INFO 
>   [regionserver/ubuntuServer/10.0.2.15:16201-EventThread]
>   zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down 2016-11-11 11:13:44,814
>   INFO  [regionserver/ubuntuServer/10.0.2.15:16201] zookeeper.ZooKeeper:
>   Session: 0x158516036c10005 closed 2016-11-11 11:13:44,814 INFO 
>   [regionserver/ubuntuServer/10.0.2.15:16201]
>   regionserver.HRegionServer: stopping server
>   ubuntuserver,16201,1478834015515; all regions closed. 2016-11-11
>   11:13:44,810 INFO  [MemStoreFlusher.0] regionserver.MemStoreFlusher:
>   MemStoreFlusher.0 exiting 2016-11-11 11:13:44,820 INFO 
>   [MemStoreFlusher.1] regionserver.MemStoreFlusher: MemStoreFlusher.1
>   exiting 2016-11-11 11:13:44,814 WARN 
>   [regionserver/ubuntuServer/10.0.2.15:16201] wal.ProtobufLogWriter:
>   Failed to write trailer, non-fatal, continuing...
>   java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.checkClosed(DFSOutputStream.java:1538)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSOutputSummer.write(FSOutputSummer.java:98)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.write(FSDataOutputStream.java:58)
>           at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
>           at com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream.refreshBuffer(CodedOutputStream.java:833)
>           at com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream.flush(CodedOutputStream.java:843)
>           at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite.writeTo(AbstractMessageLite.java:80)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.ProtobufLogWriter.writeWALTrailer(ProtobufLogWriter.java:157)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.ProtobufLogWriter.close(ProtobufLogWriter.java:130)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.FSHLog.shutdown(FSHLog.java:1079)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.wal.DefaultWALProvider.shutdown(DefaultWALProvider.java:114)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.wal.WALFactory.shutdown(WALFactory.java:216)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.shutdownWAL(HRegionServer.java:1315)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.run(HRegionServer.java:1064)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 2016-11-11 11:13:44,829 INFO  [regionserver/ubuntuServer/10.0.2.15:16201]
>   regionserver.Leases: regionserver/ubuntuServer/10.0.2.15:16201 closing
>   leases 2016-11-11 11:13:44,829 INFO 
>   [regionserver/ubuntuServer/10.0.2.15:16201] regionserver.Leases:
>   regionserver/ubuntuServer/10.0.2.15:16201 closed leases 2016-11-11
>   11:13:44,830 INFO  [regionserver/ubuntuServer/10.0.2.15:16201]
>   hbase.ChoreService: Chore service for:
>   ubuntuserver,16201,1478834015515 had [[ScheduledChore: Name:
>   ubuntuserver,16201,1478834015515-MemstoreFlusherChore Period: 10000
>   Unit: MILLISECONDS], [ScheduledChore: Name: MovedRegionsCleaner for
>   region ubuntuserver,16201,1478834015515 Period: 120000 Unit:
>   MILLISECONDS]] on shutdown 2016-11-11 11:13:48,193 INFO 
>   [HBase-Metrics2-1] impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping HBase metrics
>   system... 2016-11-11 11:13:48,194 INFO  [HBase-Metrics2-1]
>   impl.MetricsSystemImpl: HBase metrics system stopped. 2016-11-11
>   11:13:48,695 INFO  [HBase-Metrics2-1] impl.MetricsConfig: loaded
>   properties from hadoop-metrics2-hbase.properties 2016-11-11
>   11:13:48,708 INFO  [HBase-Metrics2-1] impl.MetricsSystemImpl:
>   Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s). 2016-11-11 11:13:48,708
>   INFO  [HBase-Metrics2-1] impl.MetricsSystemImpl: HBase metrics system
>   started 2016-11-11 11:13:50,001 INFO 
>   [regionserver/ubuntuServer/10.0.2.15:16201.logRoller]
>   regionserver.LogRoller: LogRoller exiting. 2016-11-11 11:13:50,002
>   INFO  [regionserver/ubuntuServer/10.0.2.15:16201]
>   regionserver.CompactSplitThread: Waiting for Split Thread to finish...
>   2016-11-11 11:13:50,002 INFO 
>   [regionserver/ubuntuServer/10.0.2.15:16201]
>   regionserver.CompactSplitThread: Waiting for Merge Thread to finish...
>   2016-11-11 11:13:50,002 INFO 
>   [regionserver/ubuntuServer/10.0.2.15:16201]
>   regionserver.CompactSplitThread: Waiting for Large Compaction Thread
>   to finish... 2016-11-11 11:13:50,002 INFO 
>   [regionserver/ubuntuServer/10.0.2.15:16201]
>   regionserver.CompactSplitThread: Waiting for Small Compaction Thread
>   to finish... 2016-11-11 11:13:50,012 INFO 
>   [regionserver/ubuntuServer/10.0.2.15:16201] ipc.RpcServer: Stopping
>   server on 16201 2016-11-11 11:13:50,012 INFO 
>   [RpcServer.listener,port=16201] ipc.RpcServer:
>   RpcServer.listener,port=16201: stopping 2016-11-11 11:13:50,017 INFO 
>   [RpcServer.responder] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.responder: stopped
>   2016-11-11 11:13:50,017 INFO  [RpcServer.responder] ipc.RpcServer:
>   RpcServer.responder: stopping 2016-11-11 11:13:50,016 INFO 
>   [regionserver/ubuntuServer/10.0.2.15:16201.leaseChecker]
>   regionserver.Leases:
>   regionserver/ubuntuServer/10.0.2.15:16201.leaseChecker closing leases
>   2016-11-11 11:13:50,026 INFO 
>   [regionserver/ubuntuServer/10.0.2.15:16201.leaseChecker]
>   regionserver.Leases:
>   regionserver/ubuntuServer/10.0.2.15:16201.leaseChecker closed leases
>   2016-11-11 11:13:50,028 INFO  [main-EventThread] zookeeper.ClientCnxn:
>   EventThread shut down 2016-11-11 11:13:50,029 INFO 
>   [regionserver/ubuntuServer/10.0.2.15:16201] zookeeper.ZooKeeper:
>   Session: 0x158516036c10004 closed 2016-11-11 11:13:50,029 INFO 
>   [regionserver/ubuntuServer/10.0.2.15:16201]
>   regionserver.HRegionServer: stopping server
>   ubuntuserver,16201,1478834015515; zookeeper connection closed.
>   2016-11-11 11:13:50,029 INFO 
>   [regionserver/ubuntuServer/10.0.2.15:16201]
>   regionserver.HRegionServer: regionserver/ubuntuServer/10.0.2.15:16201
>   exiting 2016-11-11 11:13:50,029 ERROR [main]
>   regionserver.HRegionServerCommandLine: Region server exiting
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: HRegionServer Aborted
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServerCommandLine.start(HRegionServerCommandLine.java:68)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServerCommandLine.run(HRegionServerCommandLine.java:87)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:126)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.main(HRegionServer.java:2665)
>   2016-11-11 11:13:50,031 INFO  [Thread-6] regionserver.ShutdownHook:
>   Shutdown hook starting; hbase.shutdown.hook=true;
>   fsShutdownHook=org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$ClientFinalizer@18230356
>   2016-11-11 11:13:50,033 INFO  [Thread-6] regionserver.ShutdownHook:
>   Starting fs shutdown hook thread. 2016-11-11 11:13:50,036 ERROR
>   **[Thread-82] hdfs.DFSClient: Failed to close inode 16780
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File
>   /hbase/WALs/ubuntuserver,16201,1478834015515/ubuntuserver%2C16201%2C1478834015515..meta.1478834024410.meta
>   could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1). 
>   There are 1 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this
>   operation.**
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1571)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getNewBlockTargets(FSNamesystem.java:3107)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3031)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:725)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:492)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:982)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2043)
>
> ```
>     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1411)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1364)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.addBlock(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.addBlock(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:368)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.fs.HFileSystem$1.invoke(HFileSystem.java:279)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.addBlock(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1449)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1270)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:526)
> ```
>
> 2016-11-11 11:13:50,057 INFO  [Thread-6] regionserver.ShutdownHook:
>   Shutdown hook finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

oh, I have to answer myself's question one more time.

The root cause is not permission issue. It's storage space issue. I deployed the cluster in a virtual machine with 8G hard disk space. However it was 7.8G now.

Solution: Recreated a virtual machine with 200G hard disk space.